# Incorrect Date format error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

while executing this code:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    user_name,
    employee_id,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    last_update_date,
    MAX (start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY f.employee_id) AS max_start_date,
    MAX (last_update_date) OVER (PARTITION BY f.employee_id) AS max_last_update_date
FROM 
    refadm.cg1_fnd_user f
WHERE 
    TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YY  HH:MI:SSAM') <=
          COALESCE (TO_DATE (f.end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), SYSDATE + 1)
```

Comment: what is the datatype of f.end_date?

Answer (score 3):

Don't convert `sysdate` to a date -- it is already a `date`:

```
WHERE SYSDATE <= TO_DATE(f.end_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd') OR
      f.end_date IS NULL
```

You may still get the problem, depending on what `f.end_date` looks like.  But the logic is at least simpler.

If `f.end_date` is only sometimes in `yyyy-MM-dd` format, then you can use regular expressions or a user-defined function to handle the invalid formats.

EDIT:

If `end_date` is in a different format, then use the correct format:

```
WHERE SYSDATE <= TO_DATE(f.end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') OR
      f.end_date IS NULL
```

Comment: f.end_date has date value in the format - 3/26/2013

Comment: Then you must use `TO_DATE(f.end_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')` - in case it is really a **string**, i.e. `VARCAHR2` data type.

Answer (score 0):

If your string has format '3/26/2013'  - you wrote a wrong format in to_date function. It should be  TO_DATE (f.end_date,'MM-DD-YYYY')
The whole sentence can look like

```
WHERE SYSDATE <= TO_DATE(f.end_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') OR
      f.end_date IS NULL
```